# i want to change image using for loop in js without using jQuery

Tags: javascript, for-loop

> i don't understand why this is not working? plz tell me what i missed in this code
> ** html **

```
<div id="img">
            <img class="images"src="images/boy1.jpg">
        </div>
```

** js **

```
var images = new Array();

images[0] = "/images/boy1.jpg";
images[1] = "/images/boy2.jpg";
images[2] = "/images/boy3.jpg";
images[3] = "/images/girl1.jpg";
images[4] = "/images/girl2.jpg";


function changeImg(){

    let img = document.querySelector(".images");   
    for(let i=0;i<images.length;i++){
       img.src = images[i]
    }
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",changeImg)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't working"? What specifically isn't working?

Comment: Your HTML also doesn't have an element with an id of `btn`, so that will cause issues as you won't be able to add your click event listener to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wish to achieve?

```js
var images = new Array();
var imgIndex = 0;

images[0] = "/images/boy1.jpg";
images[1] = "/images/boy2.jpg";
images[2] = "/images/boy3.jpg";
images[3] = "/images/girl1.jpg";
images[4] = "/images/girl2.jpg";


function changeImg() {
  var myImg = document.getElementById("myImg");
  if (imgIndex < images.length - 1) {
    imgIndex++;
  } else {
    imgIndex = 0;
  }

  myImg.src = images[imgIndex];
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", changeImg);
```

```html
<div id="img">
  <img id="myImg" class="images" src="images/boy1.jpg">
</div>

<button id="btn">Next</button>
```

Comment: yes... but it doesn't  start showing starting images while loop is ended when i refresh page then loop start... is it possible to show first image when after last image after clicking next btn

Comment: @Nidhisharma It does loop: once you reach the last image, if you click the "Next" button, the first image is displayed.

Answer (score 2):

try it:

```js
  var images = new Array();

    images[0] = "/images/boy1.jpg";
    images[1] = "/images/boy2.jpg";
    images[2] = "/images/boy3.jpg";
    images[3] = "/images/girl1.jpg";
    images[4] = "/images/girl2.jpg";


    function changeImg() {

    
      const imgBox = document.getElementById("img");
      for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        const img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = images[i]
        imgBox.appendChild(img)

      }
    }

    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", changeImg)
```

```html
<div id="img"></div>
<button id="btn">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop always takes the last image and sets it to be the source of the img tag, what you need to be doing is changing the index and then only set the indexed image to be the source:

```
const image = document.querySelector(".images");
let currentIndex = 0;
let images = new Array();

images[0] = "/images/boy1.jpg";
images[1] = "/images/boy2.jpg";
images[2] = "/images/boy3.jpg";
images[3] = "/images/girl1.jpg";
images[4] = "/images/girl2.jpg";

const length = images.length;

function changeImg(){
    // increment currentIndex in a circular way; after 4 comes 0 again
    currentIndex = ++currentIndex % length;
    image.src = images[currentIndex];
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", changeImg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop changes `img.src` five times immediately and so the final result is `images[4]`, you don't see the other images.